# I've rescued the Queen from the Cathedral. Now what?

Tags: chrono-trigger

The Queen was stuck in the Cathedral. She's been freed and is back in our party. Hooray!

However, I'm now stumped. Everybody in the castle, the inn, the market or the residence seems too happy about the rescuing of the real queen to aid with time travel. The Cathedral's now completely empty. The starting area only has a couple of monsters playing ball (also a monster). The forest only has the usual bunch of people. There seem to be no other points of interest in the map.

What now?

Answer (score 5):

You must first go back to where Marle vanished (that'd be the Queen's room — from the throne right and upstairs) and *only then* back to where the gate opened in the first place. Lucca has the device to reopen it.

Comment: Answering your own question I see.

Comment: @Oniros Yup! Why make others look for a solution to a problem you've already solved? :)

Comment: @badp don't forget to hit the tick icon if this answered your question!